# VBA Excel - Alterar cell entre True e False

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou a fazer um código mas como ainda sou muito verde no VBA não sei meter isto a funcionar. É muito simples, eu quero carregar numa celula e ela vai alterar um boolean entre True e False.

Eu quando carrego ele mete VERDADEIRO, mas depois se carregar lá outra vez, ou sair da celula e voltar a seleccionar ele não muda para false!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Dim mudancasAtivas As Boolean
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1:E1")) Is Nothing Then
            With Target(1, 3)
                If mudancasAtivas = True Then
                     mudancasAtivas = False
                    .value = mudancasAtivas
                ElseIf mudancasAtivas = False Then
                     mudancasAtivas = True
                    .value = mudancasAtivas
                End If
            End With
        End If

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E10000")) Is Nothing Then

            If mudancasAtivas = True Then
                Codexxx
            End If
        End If
  End If
 End Sub
```

Há alguma maneira mais fácil ou viável de fazer isto e funcionar?

Comment: Você apenas declarou a variável `mudancasAtivas`, ela não está definida, portanto ela não vai entrar no `If`..

Comment: Até rodei seu código aqui, mas você poderia descrever melhor o que você pretende fazer? Ainda não consegui entender o seu objetivo.

Comment: Eu quero que quando for a carregar no E1 ele mude a variavel mudancasAtivas para true se estiver false ou o contrário. Que é para se estiver true ele rodar o código abaixo.. Não estou a conseguir é mudar a variável sempre que carrego no E1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo, pois o código executa em dois momentos distintos. Como a variável **mudancasAtivas** é local, na 2a execução o valor que foi atribuído a ela, na 1a execução, já não vale mais.

Assim, o que você poderia fazer pra resolver isso é declarar essa variável como global no módulo da planilha.

Veja abaixo o código:

```
Dim mudancasAtivas As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1:E1")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, 3)
            If mudancasAtivas = True Then
                 mudancasAtivas = False
                .Value = mudancasAtivas
            ElseIf mudancasAtivas = False Then
                 mudancasAtivas = True
                .Value = mudancasAtivas
            End If
        End With
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E10000")) Is Nothing Then

        If mudancasAtivas = True Then
            Debug.Print "OI"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Abaixo vai uma versão reduzida e que não precisa da variável mudancasAtivas, veja:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
          Exit Sub
      End If

      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1:E1")) Is Nothing Then
          Target(1, 3).Value = Not Target(1, 3).Value
      End If

      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E10000")) Is Nothing Then
          If Cells(1, 7).Value = -1 Then
              Debug.Print "OI"
          End If
      End If
End Sub
```

Da maneira que está, os valores ficarão trocando entre 0 e -1. 0 é a constante que representa o FALSO no Excel e -1 a constante que representa o VERDADEIRO.

Caso você queira que seja trocado entre VERDADEIRO e FALSO, basta escrever na célula um desses dois valores.

Comment: Então o único problema era porque a variável não era Global? 

Resultou! Obrigado :)

Comment: Sim. O problema nesse caso é que você precisava manter o estado entre as chamadas. Para isso, você pode usar uma variável global deste módulo ou fazer como mostrei no 2o código, ou seja, utilizar o próprio estado mantido pela célula do Excel.